# Stack Overflow on Tapatalk

Tags: feature-request

I'm using [Tapatalk](http://www.tapatalk.com/) on my Android phone to follow other forums. It's a fantastic way to view forums on Android rather than using the default browser. I've started using Stack Overflow for Android app development help and would love to see Stack Overflow via the Tapatalk app on my Android phone, anyone else interested?

I think the site owners need to register with Tapatalk to allow Stack Overflow to be seen via the Tapatalk app.

Perhaps there is another Android application that allows easy access to the Stack Overflow site, if so I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: You use the word *"forum"* 7 times... I know it's nagging a bit, but maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/about?

Comment: @Arjan - I don't like seeing anyone unhappy...

Comment: are there any iPhone apps to follow stackoverflow activity?

Comment: @Linuxmint - yes Six to Eight http://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client-now-in-the-app-store use this search term http://stackapps.com/search?q=iphone+[app]

Comment: @Arjan, Yep I think your right, too may 'forums', makes painful reading.

Comment: Just to be sure... I'm *not* complaining about using some word too often. However, the word *forum* is not what we (or: I) like to refer to when talking about Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange!

Comment: Ah, so I've completely misunderstood you, what should Stack Overflow, Exchange etc be refereed too if not 'forum'?  I've just checked what an Internet Forum is according to Wiki and Stack appears to be pretty close. I'd like to understand, don't want to offend anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on Tapatalk as I know nothing about it.

However, there are Android apps available

- [DroidStack](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-1-0-10-now-with-chat-support)
- [TopStack](https://stackapps.com/questions/979/topstack-android-client-for-stack-exchange)
- [Stackwidget](https://stackapps.com/questions/821/stackwidget-for-android)

To name but a few.

Check out https://stackapps.com/ for further possibilities or use [this search query](https://stackapps.com/search?q=android+[app])

Comment: An alternative, super, I like it! uninstalling Tapatalk...

Comment: DroidStack and Stackwidget work together, superb!

Answer (score 8):

From the tapatalk web site:

> Tapatalk Forum App provides super fast on-the-go forum access to any vBulletin, IPBoard, phpBB or SMF forum

Stack Overflow is none of of those and uses a very different system than all of them.

Comment: Ah, guess that puts an end to Tapatalk so!

Comment: This is very old now, and SO has since added an API that supports posting. It's possible Tapatalk may add SO support.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on your phone, scroll down to the bottom of this site and you should see a link saying: "Download stack exchange android app". That is a pretty good solution for viewing stack exchange sites on Android I think. You can then log into the app and ask/answer questions on your mobile!

Comment: They also have an iOS app.

Comment: Or maybe just go straight to the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin).

Comment: That's possible too.